# why I get an empty request body express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

**Router**

`router.patch("/fav/:id", getFav);`

**controller**

```
const getFav = async (req, res) => {
 const { favToadd } = req.body;
 const { id } = req.params;
 try {
   const Users = await User.findById(id);
   console.log("body : ", req.body); // body :  {}
   const fav = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
     $set: { favorite: [...Users.favorite, favToadd] },
   });
   res.send(fav);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("err ", error.message);
 }
};
```

//Function to add favorites

```
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:4000/api/user/fav/${currentUser._id}`,
      {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ prd: product.props }),
      }
    );
  };
```

the item gets saved to MongoDB as **null** and then I take look at the req body it's empty,
my goal is to add an object to the favorite properties in  MongoDB document
but it gets saved as null
try different methods but nothing works I don't think I get a body from the patch request
don't know if the problem with it or in the communication between the front and the  back end it's
my first app so hopefully, the problem is in this line of code not in another part,
when I send it from postman with raw JSON it Works and gets saved at MongoDB with the properties I set

Comment: Do you have `application/json` parsing middleware installed such as `app.use(express.json())`?  If not, that's why `req.body` is empty because the body of the request has not been read and parsed.

Comment: yes, I use req.body in other request but this refuses to work

Comment: And, is that `app.use(express.json())` run BEFORE this particular route?  If so, `req.body` should not be empty for the `fetch()` code that you show.